# WPF Updating a TextBlock on Click

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have 3 buttons right now which each one of them does a specific task. Either open a Webpage or an application on the desktop. However, I want a series of instructions to follow these buttons thus why I'm using a Textblock. When I click on the Button I want the instructions to reflect which button was pressed and have it constantly changed between the 3. How would this be done?

```
    protected void passButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // I want to be able to surround this is a try catch block statement
        // because there is a "Run as Admin" A lot of users may say no and it will crash.
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        String pathWay = "C:\\blah.txt";

        try
        //Although we have a working enviornment here we still need to be able to run it as an administrator always
        //This would eliminate the need of a "Try/Catch" statement.
        {
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = pathWay;
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            myProcess.Start();

        }
        //Fixed the bug where the app would crash when the user would enter "No" instead of "yes" the App would not launch in this case.
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter so value here for logs later down the road if we run into the problem.");
        }

       // Here is where I want to be able to change the value incase the user
       // clicks another button as of right now the text block updates once
       // the block is clicked with a simple "Hello World" but if I click of the value remains the same

       textBlock.Text = "Hello world";
```

Comment: Could you post a simplified version of the application code so others may help debug it?

Comment: Hey Laylarenee, I just added some of the code above. I hope it clears some things up!

Comment: Could you add the Click Handlers for each of the three buttons? You only need to include the bit that sets the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is sounds like you want is a text box to update depending on which button was clicked?  If that's the case, I would recommend the Click Handlers (like @laylarenee suggested) by doing something similar to this:

```
private bool btn1_Clicked = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn1_Clicked = true;
}
```

Repeat that for all 3 buttons (btn2_Clicked,btn3_Clicked).  If you want to put your logic in the button handler (like you have done above) then you can make another function called update_Text where you check those variables you set and update the text box:

```
if(btn1_Clicked == true)
{
   // put your textbox update in here
}
```

This may be a bit of a longer way around, but would get the job done for sure. Just be sure you set the other button click variables back to false if another button is clicked to keep things clean.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah the Click Handling actually ended up working for me I ended up doing something like this for each topic: 

 var tb = sender as TextBlock;

            if (tb == null)
            {
                textBlock.Text = "Working on it";
            }

Comment: If this answered your question, you should mark it as complete.